# Sending variable over serial

Tags: serial

I have an LCD keypad shield that I'm using to control a Catalex serial MP3 module and I have an int variable that has the volume setting which can go from 1 to 30. I'm trying to send the variable to the module but it's not working. Here's the code for the serial request:

```cpp
void SetAttractVolume() {
  SerialString = SerialString2 + AttractVolume;
  delay(20);
  Send_buf[0] = 0x7e; // starting byte
  Send_buf[1] = 0xff; // version
  Send_buf[2] = 0x06; // the number of bytes of the command without starting byte and ending byte
  Send_buf[3] = 0x06; //
  Send_buf[4] = 0x00; // 0x00 = no feedback, 0x01 = feedback
  Send_buf[5] = 0x00;
  Send_buf[6] = 0x12;
  Send_buf[7] = 0xef; //ending byte
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++) {
    mySerial.write(Send_buf[i]); // send bit to serial mp3
    Serial.print(Send_buf[i], HEX); // send bit to serial monitor in pc
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

"0x12" is the volume control, you set the 12 to any number from 1 to 30 to change it, I thought I could just put my variable in there, like this:

```cpp
void SetAttractVolume() {
  SerialString = SerialString2 + AttractVolume;
  delay(20);
  Send_buf[0] = 0x7e; // starting byte
  Send_buf[1] = 0xff; // version
  Send_buf[2] = 0x06; // the number of bytes of the command without starting byte and ending byte
  Send_buf[3] = 0x06; //
  Send_buf[4] = 0x00; // 0x00 = no feedback, 0x01 = feedback
  Send_buf[5] = 0x00;
  Send_buf[6] = 0xAttractVolume;
  Send_buf[7] = 0xef; //ending byte
  for (uint8_t i=0; i<8; i++) {
    mySerial.write(Send_buf[i]) ;//send bit to serial mp3
    Serial.print(Send_buf[i],HEX);//send bit to serial monitor in pc
  }
  Serial.println();
}
```

This doesn't compile, I know it's not the correct way to do it, but I want to know how to do it right.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `This doesn't compile`  ... you did not present the complete code amd you fid not say anything about any errors ... i suggest that you learn some programming ... at least examine some of the example sketches in the arduino IDE

Comment: `Send_buf[6] = 0xAttractVolume;` makes no sense; `0x` is used to indicate a hex number follows; you can't just stick a variable name to it. Try `Send_buf[6] = AttractVolume;` and see what happens.